# Why does Mathematica fail to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(ax^2) dx$ whereas Wolfram Alpha seems to be able to do it?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I was symbolically computing

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(ax^2) dx $$

Via the command:

`Integrate[Sin[a*x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]`

But it seems to fail with mathematica, see below:

[image]

This same computation carried out on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%20sin%28ax%5E2%29%20dx%2C%20x%20from%200%20to%20infinity) does compute successfully, see below:

[image]

So I'm pretty sure it should be tractable by Mathematica as well. I'm not sure why this computation doesn't work. If I had to *guess* the root cause, my first guess would be that wolfram alpha assumes $a$ is real whereas mathematica DOES NOT assume this and hence is not able to find a result. To me this would mean that I need to pass in an assumption "$a$ is real" to get this to work. But this all very much just me using my imagination as opposed to trying to deduce from some facts at hand.

I'm Using Mathematica 13.0.1 on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: I use both Mathematica V13.2 and V13.3 to integrate and get results.

Comment: Also V 13.3.1 gives answer ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEdk8.png)  Wolfram alpha must using latest version of Mathemtaica.

Comment: V13.0.1.0 (Windows 10) seems to require `Assumptions` to get an answer:  `Integrate[Sin[a*x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]`.

Comment: This is a Fresnel integral which is described in detail here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more about Wolfram|Alpha (which is off-topic here) than Mathematica. Indeed, it looks like it is assuming $a \in \mathbb R$; you can click on _Give us your feedback_ on Wolfram|Alpha and complain about this unmentioned assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica is right and W|A isn't. Indeed, in 13.3.1 on Windows 10

```
Integrate[Sin[a*x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Sqrt[Abs[a]])/(2 a),  a \[Element] Reals]`

Let us consider `a==r+I*s`, where `s!=0`:

```
TrigExpand[Sin[r*x^2 + I*s*x^2]]
```

> `Cosh[s x^2] Sin[r x^2] + I Cos[r x^2] Sinh[s x^2]`

and then

```
Integrate[Cosh[s x^2] Sin[r x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {r, s} \[Element] Reals && s != 0]
```

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of Cosh[s x^2] Sin[r x^2] does not converge on {0,[Infinity]}.

The same with the imaginary part.

Comment: Simpler:`Integrate[Sin[(r + I*s)*x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {r, s} \[Element] Reals && s != 0]` performs "Integrate::idiv: Integral of Sin[(r+I s) x^2] does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}.".